# How to exclude internal dependencies from vendor folder when using dep for golang

Tags: go, dependencies, dependency-management

I have a project that depends on two other projects in the internal git repo. Which is already present in GOPATH.
The problem I am facing is that, `dep-init -gopath` will still copy those projects under vendor/ directory.

Consequently the GoLand IDE I am using is confused where from the dependency is to be resolved. (I want it to resolve from GOPATH and not Vendor directory) If I delete the vendor/ directory, the program will run.

My Gopkg.toml file looks like:

```
[[constraint]]
  branch = "master"
  name = "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"

[[constraint]]
  branch = "master"
  name = "github.com/stretchr/testify"

[[constraint]]
  branch = "master"
  name = "gitlab.internal.com/vapi/goabc"

[[constraint]]
  branch = "master"
  name = "gitlab.internal.com/vapi/goxyz"

[prune]
  go-tests = true
  unused-packages = true
```

Where
`"gitlab.internal.com/vapi/goabc"` and `"gitlab.internal.com/vapi/goxyz"`
are the internal projects that this project depends on.

I tried adding the dependencies to ignored list [https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/Gopkg.toml.html#ignored]

But goxyz and goabc are still downloaded to vendor/
How can I get rid of them from the vendor directory?

Comment: The ignore list seems the right approach. Please show how you did that.

Comment: Thank you! I think I missed the wildcard notation at the end. Posting it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ignored = [
  "gitlab.internal.com/vapi/goabc*",
  "gitlab.internal.com/vapi/goxyz*"
]
```

Did the trick, earlier I hadn't placed the wildcard and other package imports forced the dep to download the project anyway.

Comment: That can probably be shortened to "gitlab.com/internal.com/*"

Comment: not if you have other gitlab internal projects such as  "gitlab.internal.com/vapi2/whatver*" or   "gitlab.internal.com/vapi/goccc*" and u don't want to ignore them